# Emacs lisp regex to extract current relative path from buffer-file-name

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I am trying to extract the current directory relative to the home directory from the `buffer-file-name` variable. Consider:

```
(defun test ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((fn "/home/user/dir1/dir2/file.txt"))
    (when (string-match "^.*?/user/" fn)
      (let ((temp (replace-match "${HOME}/" nil nil fn)))
        (when (string-match "/.*?$" temp)
          (message (replace-match "/" nil nil temp)))))))
```

Here I would like to get `${HOME}/dir1/dir2/` but instead I get `${HOME}/`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```lisp
(let ((str "/home/user/dir1/dir2/file.txt"))
  (when (string-match "^.*?/user/" str)
    (file-name-directory (replace-match "${HOME}/" nil nil str))))
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, but I wonder what was the problem with my code?

Comment: Regex being greedy I guess. Maybe [^/]* would fix it.

Comment: Yes, "/[^/]*$" fixes it.

Comment: Ok, but I thought `.*?` would be the non-greedy version of `.*`. See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression

Comment: Yes, that's the spec. It's non-greedy going forwards.
But the way you put it, you give the regex no choice.
Compare `/.*c` and `/.*$`: the latter *has* to go all the way
to the end of the line. The greed is forwards, not backwards.

Comment: Ok, that is interesting :) I agree. Thanks!

Comment: Er, there is `file-relative-name`.  This regexp foo is superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

Use `file-relative-name`:

```
(concat "$HOME/" (file-relative-name (buffer-file-name) (expand-file-name "~")))
```

`(expand-file-name "~")` gives the home directory of the current user.  `file-relative-name` then converts the given file name into a file name relative this directory.